# 3603 User configuration issue error in Azure function on Azure Data Factory

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I have an Azure HTTP Trigger function and when I sent a POST request via POSTMAN this function work correctly (the below pic).

[image]

Now, I added this function to Azure Data Factory and I wanna run this function with the pipeline.
I configured the parameter but I received an error. I don't know how should I send a URL request in the ADF pipeline and I received the below error.

[image]

[image]

My azure function code is [here](http://txt.do/18wc5)

New Error is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is because your response from the Azure Function is not proper JSON. You have the return body like this:

```
 "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
```

It needs to be formatted like JSON where that message is the value of the "body" property.

Something like this:

```
{"body":"my custom response"}
```

Comment: Thank you, I changed my body but now I received a new error. I added the end of the post.

Comment: @Shadi can you check your linked service to make sure it can still connect and the function hasn't moved or had the name changed?